# Molten vs Liquid

Tags: phase

When I start studying electrochemistry, I learn the words “molten” and “aqueous”. I don't have a problem for “aqueous”, but I'm a little bit confused about “molten”.

For me, “molten” means melt, which means to become liquid from solid. But why do we say *molten* lead(II) bromide instead of *liquid* lead(II) bromide?

I mean both are the same, but liquid is arguably easier to understand.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

As you said, the meaning is exactly the same. Molten reduces the ambiguity, because you emphasize that you know, that it is solid substance at laboratory conditions and you heat it to become liquid (while staying pure substance).

As an example, the "electrolysis of liquid sodium chloride" is in principle enough to tell you all about the process, but as we often like to dissolve the salt in water, you might be slightly unsure, whether the meaning is 100% clear. Therefore "electrolysis of molten sodium chloride" is better choice.

Answer (score 1):

Molten is melted from a solid. Liquid means it exists as a liquid in room temperature. Molten substances exist as solids in room temperature. Thus the difference between molten and liquid.