# Difference between some terms relating to liquids

Tags: aqueous-solution, solutions, terminology

So my chemistry teacher, when she talks about liquid substances she talks about them in reference to 3 words. She refers to liquid substance with one of these 3 words-

1)Aquesous form

2)Solution form

3)Molten form

Can anyone please tell me the difference between these terms?

Comment: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/32008/molten-vs-liquid

Comment: well what about solution form??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take table salt, sodium chloride, for example.

If you take table salt and dissolve it in water, you are making a salt solution.

Any solution that uses water as the solvent is an aqueous solution. If, for example, you dissolved salt in ethyl alcohol, that would still be a solution but it would not be aqueous.

Now imagine you took salt and heated it really, really strongly and melted it. Just like ice melts to become water, table salt can melt too, just that it's at a much higher temperature. That's a molten liquid. In this case, there is no solvent added.

Answer (score 1):

so I will explain you.
will aqueous is the term used for those solutions in which water is used as a solvent.
solution consists of two components that is solvent and solute and it is a type of mixture.
molten state is used for those when a solid substance is heated and it is melted and when cooled again it changes into solid state.